# How to get number of rows with timestamp between 10am and now?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run a T-SQL query that would return all rows that contain a timestamp between `00:00:00` and now for any given date.

I've used the following code, but this only returns items within the past 24 hours:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE timestamp_closed =  DATE(GETDATE()-1);
```

Comment: Well [don't use between](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: You want to look at only the **time** portion?  If so, then you need to stripping out the date portion.  Are you on SQL 2008?

Comment: I answered mine thinking you were only looking at the time portion....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have the number of rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM *yourtable*
WHERE timestamp_closed BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE timestamp_closed BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AND GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build the datevalue for "Today at 00:00:00" and now and then do a

```
WHERE timestamp_closed >= "Today at 00:00:00" and timestamp_closed<=GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (timestamp_closed >  CAST(@specificDate AS DATE)
AND timestamp_closed <= GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably wrap this in a function.

```
select * 
from table
where datepart(hh,timestamp_closed)*100 + datepart(mi,timestampclosed) < 
    datepart(hh,getdate())*100 + datepart(mi,getdate())
```